# Why is this voltage "negative" in this simple BJT circuit polarization?

Tags: bjt, simulation, inverting-amplifier

A question about this circuit was posted and immediately deleted.

It is a simple circuit, but I found this when I simulated it.

First, DC analysis, nothing strange:

[image]

Then analyzing more: parameters DC Analysis, Globals Settings : Standard. [microcap12](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulml1ukc1xv1h2w/mc12cd.zip?dl=0)

[image]

[image]

One can see that there is a Vc "negative" voltage between 1 < V1 < 7 V.  I am amazed by this result.

Ok, the BJT "model" can contain some "generator", but is it really possible that Vc can become "negative" in this simple circuit?

EDIT: for comparison, BC547 and BC847 (this one is ok) parameters used

*** > From file mc12cd\library\MSBJT.LBR
NPN Amplifer transistors
.MODEL BC547 NPN (BF=437.641 BR=2.55977 CJC=6.40421p CJE=19.7395p
IKF=544.354m IKR=985.432             IS=7.88857f ISC=7.52015p ISE=.0000161327f
ITF=9.88981m  MJC=316.254m MJE=312.92m                NE=1.24119 NF=968.124m
RE=1.23191 TF=374.789p TR=10n
VAF=100 VJC=700m VJE=770.586m VTF=10 XTF=499.98m)

> From file mc12cd\library\MSBJT.LBR
> NPN Amplifer transistors
> From file mc12cd\library\PH_BJT.LIB
> .MODEL BC847 NPN (BF=324.4 BR=8.29 CJC=3.347E-12 CJE=1.244E-11    FC=0.979
> IKF=0.109 IKR=0.09  IRB=5E-06  IS=1.822E-14 ISC=9.982E-12 ISE=2.894E-16
> ITF=0.3131 MJC=0.391 MJE=0.3656  MJS=0.333 NC=1.763  NE=1.4 NF=0.9932 NR=0.9931
> RB=10 RBM=5 RC=0.7014 RE=0.649 TF=4.908E-10 TR=9E-08
> VAF=82 VAR=17.9  VJC=0.5463 VJE=0.7579  VJS=0.75  VTF=2.927 XCJC=0.6193  XTF=9.51)

Comment: What step size did you use?

Comment: @Antonio51:  It is probably related to the effect I asked about in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537899/what-is-this-effect-i-am-seeing-in-a-current-voltage-plot-of-a-2n2222-npn-transi) last year.

Comment: @Andyaka  I add parameters in Q.

Comment: @JRE ... Ok for the answer is the cited post ... But the analysis was made with a "negative" voltage at the input, then I understand. Here, no negative voltage was used ... So, I don't understand. The only answer I could find is in "model" and "generator" used inside  ... Will try to modify all parameters on generic BJT to see what parameter is of concern.

Comment: Try to use BC847C insted.

Comment: @Antonio51 LTspice shows [a similar ***shape***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WpDu.png) but it does NOT go negative. However, there ***is*** an effect that can take place as the BE junction emits light and where that light (which cannot normally be seen in a packaged BJT) does cause photo-generated charges and these ***can*** cause the collector to go negative. Just not in this circumstance, so far as I'm aware. It is most noticeable with the collector open and very very lightly loaded by the instrument measuring the voltage there. I doubt your simulator handles this case.

Comment: @G36  BC847 does not show this strange "behavior". I will compare the parameters to find the "guilty" ...   :-)

Comment: @jonk  Ok for the shape, I understand it. Ok also for the "photo-generated" charges, but I don't remember that this phenomenon is taken into account in the simulator.

Comment: @Antonio51 I *also* don't think it is taken into account by the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

After [some search](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/UserGuide/elements_fr.html) within parameters, I found that the "BR" parameter has something to do with this phenomenon.
However, I found that some new parameters were added to the BJT BC847C.
To illustrate, I "created" some BJT_bis, changing this BR parameter.

[image]

And the results with changing only this parameter (see Vc1 and Vc3).

[image]

Comment: [Here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78R6G.png) just changing **BR** alone. Note that other parameters were likely different than yours. But do take note that at no time does the collector dive below 0 V in LTspice simulation. It may be that **BR** interacts with some other parameter where LTspice might replicate your results. But I can't tell, as yet, and it certainly isn't only **BR** by itself.

Comment: << it certainly isn't only BR by itself >>, yes, I agree. I changed quasi all parameters of BJT I had in the simulator, (one by one, at one time only) and it was the most significant. Sure, it is a "little" problem with the "model" used by simulators. I am searching for a "note" where all these parameters are "evaluated". Anyway, thanks for you simulation. :-)

Comment: I tester **BR** of the BJTs I have on my bench at 1mA (BC548B and BC337-25).  Most of them are from Philips and ST.  And for BC548B the **BR**  was around 8 and for BC337-20 around 38.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your simulator program is and the specific simulation parameters, models and SPICE netlist you use, it is difficult to replicate.

Anyway, that voltage goes negative for some millivolts, so it could either be some simulation artifact or some "real effect" due to parasitic inductance/capacitance of the BJT model.

Comment: Ok. Will add simulator also in Q. http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12.zip

Comment: Changed link https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110